# after running eas build " eas build -p android --profile preview " this command fails

Tags: react-native

I got this error while building:

[image]

My app is running perfectly fine on expo it gets published also on expo server but not able to build without it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your print, there's an error in the file: `android/settings.gradle`, more specifically on line 10.

Since you didn't post the file, neither the log message that the images recommends to, I'm assuming the line has something like `includeBuild[...]`.

If so, change whatever is on that line to the following:

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
```

Got this solution [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22584#issuecomment-1635872980).

Don't forget to mark this answer as a solution if it solves your problem!